# How to find the speed using x,y,z axis values?

Tags: iphone

hai,In my application i want to calculate the spped based on x,y,z values.So How to find the speed using x,y,z axis values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrate the acceleration of each axis then add together the velocity vectors, and finally take the magnitude. You now have speed.

Comment: Iam weak in physics so please tell me how to take the magnitude

Comment: Look up "adding together vectors" in relation to maths.

Comment: Assuming you have the 3D velocity vector `(x, y, z)`, the speed can be calculated using Pythagorus' theorem: `speed = sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`.

Comment: K.Thank You.And one small doubt.How to get the device weight programatically?

Comment: You will need to make an HTTP request to Apple's iPhone Specifications page and parse the HTML, you will be able to retrieve the the device's weight.

Answer (score -1):

keep update interval of accelerometer to  1 i.e.

```
accelerometer.updateInteval=1f;
```

then in the following delegate method

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *) acc didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
}
```

get the acceleration value by acceleration.x

You will have to store the previous value in some variable

difference between the previous value and current value will give you the speed along x axes